# Javascript - loop through array of numbers and only allow them to be clicked if the other numbers are/ or are not clicked?

Tags: javascript, loops, click, event-listener

i am working on a game where you get random numbers 1-25 in individual squares, you also get random colors and font sizes. I have all that set up at this point but what i am struggling with is implementing a check that will check if these numbers have been clicked in the sequence one after another.  So, when you start the game and have your numbers from 1 through 25......i want the person to be able to click on 1 then on 2 then on 3 and have the following tests happen:

- #1 is always clickable since its the first number in a sequence.
- #2 is not clickable unless # 1 has been clicked. # 3 is not clickable unless #1 and #2 have been clicked and so on....once its successfully clicked, background color changes.

I understand i need to loop through my random numbers and assign .eventListener to them.

So i came close with this line of code:
if (squares[i].textContent = numArray[i] === 1) squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() { return squares[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'})

I can see that it is identify 1 in this case but everything is being displayed as true or false instead of numbers.  I am not sure where to go from here or how i can check for clicked boxes in the correct order.

Thank you so much for taking your time to read this and help me understand a solution.

```js
let   startBtn      = document.querySelector('.start-btn')
let   resetBtn      = document.querySelector('.reset-btn')
let   timer         = document.querySelector('.time__countdown')
const squares       = [...document.querySelectorAll('.square')];
let   gameStarted   = false;
let   counter       = 60
let   timeInterval;


startBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame)

function startGame() {
  gameStarted = true;

  if (gameStarted === true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = '#2A3166'
      })
    }
  }
  randomNumber()

  timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    counter--
    if (counter >= 0) {
      timer.innerHTML = `Time left: ${counter}`
    }
  }, 1000)
}

function getRandomColor() {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function randomNumber() {
  const numArray = []

  for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
    numArray.push(i)
  }

  numArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25)
    squares[i].textContent = numArray[i]
    squares[i].style.fontSize = random + 15 + "px";
    squares[i].style.color = getRandomColor()
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = '#000000'
  }
}

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearInterval(timeInterval)
  counter = 60
  timer.innerHTML = `Time left: 60`
  gameStarted = false
  squares.forEach((n) => {
    n.textContent = "";
    n.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: #6688CC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #ACBFE6;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.time {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.btn {
  margin: 1em;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="time">
    <p class="time__countdown">Time left: 60</p>
  </div>
  <grid class="grid">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </grid>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn start-btn">Start Game</button>
    <button class="btn reset-btn">Reset Game</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: In addition to my answer is this tip: don't assign event listeners on the fly. Assign them in the beginning, then use logic to determine what they should do (nothing or something) on the fly. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Ah, i see!! So you are controlling squares via adding and removing their classes, as far as which have been clicked and what you can do with them. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet demonstrating what I think you are looking for. Note how I first loop through and give each square an identifying attribute. Then I compare that to the number of the last one clicked. Comments are in the code.

```js
let ct = 1;
let currentNum = 0;
let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid .square');

squares.forEach(s => {
  //give it something to identify itself with
  s.setAttribute('data-num', ct++)
  s.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // get my number, convert to a number
    let mynum = +e.target.dataset.num
    //compare to the currentNum
    if (mynum - 1 === currentNum) {
      //deselect current square
      document.querySelector('.square-selected')?.classList.remove('square-selected');
      // update new square
      e.target.classList.add('square-selected');
      //update currentNum
      currentNum = mynum;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: #6688CC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #ACBFE6;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.square {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.square-selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.time {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.btn {
  margin: 1em;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<grid class="grid">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Editor() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = React.useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const generatenumbers = () => {
    const numbersT = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      numbersT.push({
        id: i,
        value: i,
        clickable: i === 0,
      });
    }

    setNumbers(numbersT);
  };

  const onClick = (id) => {
    setNumbers((prev) => {
      const index = prev.findIndex((number) => number.id === id);
      prev[index].clickable = false;
      if (index + 1 < prev.length) {
        prev[index + 1].clickable = true;
      }
      return [...prev];
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className='flex'>
      <input onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)} className='m-5' />
      <button onClick={generatenumbers} className='m-5'>
        Generate Numbers
      </button>
      <div className='flex flex-wrap'>
        {numbers.map((number) => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                if (number.clickable) {
                  onClick(number.id);
                }
              }}
              key={number.id}
              className='m-5 rounded-full items-center justify-center flex'
              style={{
                width: '50px',
                height: '50px',
                backgroundColor: number.clickable ? 'green' : 'red',
              }}
            >
              {number.value}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Visuals: only greens are allowed to be clicked]

Comment: This doesn't really address the real world question of how to implement a solution. Maybe expand your code to include some logic to answer OP's question of how to implement listeners for the task

Comment: @Kinglish I hope it does now :)

Comment: I appreciate your effort and the upvote shows someone else does as well. The original question didn't mention React so the answer should probably be vanilla javascript. Also, without comments or explanation it's difficult to learn from it.

Comment: @Kinglish, thank you for trying to help me. I appreciate it. Yes i upvoted his comment for trying to help me, but im still very confused with his answer with React. I am still a JS beginner.

Comment: @AkhtarZaman I really don't understand the React solution, it was easier to understand what you were doing before, where you assigned clicked and then sorted through it. Could you post that solution again please if you have time.